# Hide clicked row based on row.id using Bootstrap Table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) set up like this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" 
      id="table"
      data-id-field="id">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        ...
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>bootstrap-table</td>
        ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to hide row's that are clicked using the row's id:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        $table.bootstrapTable('hideRow', { uniqueId: row.id});
    });
});
```

But nothing happens.  My troubleshooting so far seems to indicate I don't have the `{ uniqueId: row.id}` part right.

The [Bootstrap Table docs](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods) for `hideRow` says:

> Hide the specified row. The param must contain at least one of the
>   following properties: index: the row index. uniqueId: the value of the
>   uniqueId for that row.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43Tesseracts/3n5q7ax4/) showing my problem of rows not hiding when clicked.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution. You need to pass `index` of currently row.

So, first row has index 0, second has index 1 , and so on..

```
$(function () {
   var $result = $('#eventsResult');
   var $table = $('#table');

   $table.on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
      $result.text('Event: click-row.bs.table on: ' + row.id);
      $table.bootstrapTable('hideRow', {index:$element.index(),isIdField:  true});
   });
});
```

Comment: But the docs show I should be able to use the uniqueID field, as shown in the quoted section?

Comment: Good, so I'm not crazy. What is  `isIdField:  true` for?  It works with this removed as well.

Comment: For me it's not worked without isidField. `isIdField` indicate that index is a unique identifier for each row. Please take a look here : https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/583

Comment: I figured it out.  They use two id attributes: idField (data-id-field) and uniqueID (data-unique-id) and I was setting the wrong one.  Once data-unique-id is set to the ID column, `{ uniqueId: row.id}` works.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't answer the question, which was how to hide with row.id